# i am not getting json response, instead getting json object.. how to fix it

Tags: jquery, json

I am sending a url to get the json response, but i am getting response as object instead of "proper response" (json data).. what is wrong here..

```
var JsonHandler = function(){
    return{
        json : function(url){
            return $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                return data;
            });
        }
    }
};

(function ($) {

    var path = "js/data.json";
    var getJson = new JsonHandler();
    console.log(getJson.json(path));// i am getting a object instead of json response..

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: did u try to do `$.parseJSON(getJson.json(path))`??

Comment: You can't return data from the `$.getJSON` callback this way, it is an `async` call.

Comment: I think `$.getJSON` parses the response, so it works as it should.

Comment: @t.niese, help me the correct way to get the json response..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle your logic in the callback. How you should do that depends on your code.

If you put `console.dir(data)` instead of `return data;` you should see your response.

So you should  put the corresponding code that should do something with the data there. Or us [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) or [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind your callback to an Object. But no matter how you create the callback you pass to the `getJson`, it must be the *origin* of the execution path where you use the data.

To illustrate the async behavior check this modification of your code:

```
var JsonHandler = function(){
    return{
        json : function(url){
            return $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                console.log("data received");
                console.dir(data);
            });
        }
    }
};

(function ($) {

    var path = "js/data.json";
    var getJson = new JsonHandler();
    console.log("before json request");
    getJson.json(path);// i am getting a object instead of json response..
    console.log("after json request");

})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT**

Here an example of a pub/sub system **(the code is currently more pseudo code - haven't tested it for syntax error, but i'll fix probably existing errors in a few hours)**

```
var JsonHandler = {
    request : function( url, params, key ) {
        $.getJSON(url, params, function(data){
            //because of js scopes the 'key'  is the one that is used for requesting the data
            JsonHandler._publishData(data, key);
        });
    },

    _subcribers : {},

    /* 
        key could also be path like this: 
                      /news/topic1
                      /news/topic2
                      /news

        so code  subscribes for '/new'  it will be notifed for  /news/topic1, /news/topic2,  /news
    */
    subscribe : function( key, callback ) {

        /*
        The path logic is missing here but should not be that problematic to added if you understood the idea 

        */

        this._subcribers[key] = this._subcribers[key]||[];
        this._subcribers[key].push(callback);

    },


    _publishData : function( data, key ) {
        /*
        check if there are subscribers for that key and if yes call notify them
                    This part is also missing the path logic mention above, is just checks for the key
        */
        if ( this._subcribers[key] ) {
            var subscribers = this._subcribers[key];

            for( var i = 0, count = subscribers.length ; i<count ; i++ ) {
                subscribers[i](data,key);
            }
        }

    }


}

var AnObject = function() {
}

AnObject.prototype = {
    updateNews : function(data, key) {
        console.log("received data for key: "+ key);
        console.dir(data);
    }
};


var obj = new AnObject();

//add a simple callback
JsonHandler.subscribe( "/news", function(data, key ) ) {
    console.log("received data for key: "+ key);
    console.dir(data);
});

//add a callback to a 'method' of an object
JsonHandler.subscribe( "/news", obj.updateNews.bind(obj) );


JsonHandler.request("some/url",{/* the parameters */}, "/news");
```

Comment: In my app development, i do have number of ajax request, i decided to centralize.. that's what i am trying..

Comment: As i said it depends on your app structor. Personally i prefere a `publish` `subscribe` system or other Event based execution of code. So on part of the code can say `"call this callback if a certain kind of data is received"` and the central part where you receive the data you check which callbacks where registered for this and call this callbacks.

Comment: sounds great. if possible can you make a small example?(in case have time..?)

Comment: I added a pseudocode like example, as noted i'll fix syntax error later. If you have questions feel free to ask. But i suggest you to do some search for pub sub system, notifications or event driven communication in the net, before you choose one of the solutions, so that you have an overview what these solutions can do and if they fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` doesn't return the JSON. It is asynchronous. Calling `return` in the callback won't change this.

Instead, use this:

```
var JsonHandler = function(callback){
    return {
        json : function(url){
            return $.getJSON(url, callback);
        }
    }
};

(function ($) {

    var path = "js/data.json";
    var getJson = new JsonHandler(function(data){console.log(data)});
    getJson.json(path);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: At least in chrome this triggers an `TypeError: Illegal invocation` error because `log` is not executed in _context_  of `console`

Comment: thats ok, because the `log` is not called as itself, but as part of `console`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "frmTrialBalance.aspx/GetTheTrialBalanceOriginalCurrPriorTwoQuarter",
              data: "{ CompanyId:'" + s + "',EndDate:'" + datet + "'}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (msg) {


                 ***var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);***

                  LoopGetTrialBalanceORIGINALPriorYearMonthQuarter(data);
                  IncreaseIframeHeight();
              },
              error: AjaxFailed
          });*emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do all your code inside callback function, there you get data object. $.getJSON return XMLHTTPRequest object.

```
    var JsonHandler = function () {
        return {
            json: function (url) {
                $.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }
    };

    (function ($) {
        var path = "js/data.json";
        var getJson = new JsonHandler();
        getJson.json(path); // i am getting a object instead of json response..
    })(jQuery);
```